# I want to change login type of a local user to a network (AD) user

Tags: login, active-directory

I am using macOS 10.12, Sierra, and I've two local accounts (the one created during unboxing and a backup one).

This is a work laptop and I would like to use my Active Directory credentials to login instead of the loca account. I would also like to get integrated network login etc... but this would be a bonus, it's not a requirement.

I've followed [Join your Mac to a network account server](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21988?locale=it_IT) and read [Best Practices for Integrating OS X with Active Directory](http://training.apple.com/pdf/Best_Practices_for_Integrating_OS_X_with_Active_Directory.pdf).

I can easily join the Mac to the domain and can use AD Utilities to browse objects inside the domain so I assume it's working.
Now I cannot find how to 'link' my existing local account to a specific AD account.

The accounts are:

- local account: simoneavogadro  (/Users/simoneavogadro)  display "Simone Avogadro"
- Active directory account: simoneavogadro  (simoneavogadro@wiselab.it) display name: "Simone Avogadro"

Currently, if I logout & login I must use the local password to login.  The AD one will not work.  This makes sense to me since I can't find how to 'link' the two things (how to  tell the Mac which AD Object to bind for login)

Comment: So the Login Window users shakes when entering your AD username and password? Also, do you plan on using a local home directory or network home directory?

Comment: I want to use a local home directory and to be able to login even when offline. I don't see any 'option' to use a network login, I tried:
 wiselab\simoneavogadro  and simoneavogadro as usernames but in both cases the password field shakes.

Comment: any hint on log files to check ?

Comment: You can enable the option to show network users at the Login Window, which may help. If `domain\username` isn't working then try `username@domain`?

Answer (score 1):

Once AD logins are working as expected I think the best answer here is to re-use your current home folder rather than trying to link accounts.

Since you're using a local home for the AD user you can shuffle the home folders and update the ownership. Be sure to do this from another account- not the local user or the AD user (you may have to create a temporary admin user).

To be clear, don't do this until you have AD logins working properly...   :)

For example:

```
sudo mv /Users/aduser /Users/aduser-orig
sudo mv /Users/localuser /Users/aduser
sudo chown -R aduser:staff /Users/aduser
```

Comment: pretty interesting, thanks. However I don't really understand why I 'cannot' login using AD credentials, I don't find any hint if this is due to the local and remote account using the same username or what else

Comment: Oh, the local user and AD user have the same username? That might be a problem... Sorry, I'm not an AD expert so not sure why it's failing off hand.